# click at element by option value

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

Need to click at element by visible text at option. It works if i do:

```
click 'option[value="29"]'
```

but need to click at option region, not value

```
region = "NY"
if list.include?(region)
click ???'options[region]'
```

css element is:

```
<option value="29">NY</option>
```

Comment: you want to click on option which has visible text "NY"...right??

Comment: Yea. And visible text must be an variable which I declare earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve the problem with reg exp.

```
var = '29'
ff.select_list(:id => 'reg-region').select_value(/#{var}/)
```